# Z-index messes up the navbar CSS

Tags: css, css-position, z-index, fixed

I have a problem with the z index on the fixed navbar menu. When i put position fixed on the header and the hamburger icon , the hamburger icon disappears behind the navbar. When there isn't z-index the navbar is ok, but when i scroll it seems to go behind the main content. I have a picture. I really don't know what to do .
[image]

```css
.header-container {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin: auto !important;
/*    z-index: 2;*/

}


label i {
    position: fixed;
    top: 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #888 !important;
/*    z-index: 3;*/
  

}
```

```html
 <input type="checkbox" id="menu-toggle" class="menu-icon" />
    <label for="menu-toggle" class="menu-icon"><i class="fa fa-bars mt-2"></i></label>

    <div class="container-content">
        <header>
            <div class="header-container pb-3 pb-lg-0 pb-mg-0 d-flex justify-content-between">
                <div class="slideout-sidebar order-1">
                    <ul class="d-md-flex flex-md-column flex-lg-row mt-md-4">
                        <li class="brd mr-md-4 align-self-center menu">МЕНИ</li>
                        <li class=" order-lg-last btn-order"> <button class="btn" type="submit">НАРАЧАЈТЕ ВЕДНАШ</button></li>
                        <li class="brd border-bottom border-top border-primary d-none ">КОНТАКТИРАЈТЕ НЕ</li>
                        <li class="brd d-none">УСЛОВИ ЗА КОРИСТЕЊЕ</li>
                        <li class=" border-bottom border-primary d-none brd">РЕСТОРАНИ</li>
                        <li class="order-lg-first mr-md-4 text-center brd align-self-center">
                            <a class="">МК</a>
                            <div class="d-inline-block 
         language-line"> | </div>
                            <a class="">EN</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div class="mx-auto mx-lg-0 mt-2">
                    <img src="./images/logo.png" alt="dominoslogo" class="navbar-brand" />
                </div>

                <div class="cart mt-2">
                    <i class="fas fa-shopping-basket header-cart d-lg-none"></i>
                    <span class="header-cart-order d-lg-none">0</span>
                </div>
            </div>

        </header>
```

Answer (score 0):

The higher the z-index the upper the content. When the navbar is behind the content give her a higher z-index.

Comment: you can give a z-index like 99 or higher